# Drop-down menu of pages in parent category

Tags: wordpress

Re: Wordpress - I want to create a standard `<select>` dropdown menu which lists the child pages in a specified parent category.

I want into insert this into a page, rather than into my template. Is there a certain shortcode I can use?

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

No you will need to make a template, or register your own shortcode
http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API